Implementing react web app into already existing website
I have a standard HTML/CSS/JS website, and in one of the pages, www.mywebsite.com/shop, I'd like to implement a React app. Is this possible, or would I need to implement it in a separate subdomain, such as shop.mywebsite.com?
One thing I noticed right away is the root file needs to be index.html which conflicts with the already existing index.html file. I'd like the react page to be named shop.html. Also, I run the HTML page by entering php -S 127.0.0.1:4300. I'm guessing that would not instantiate the react app even if it was in the same directory. I read this documentation but I'm not really sure how creating a Node.js environment would work with an HTML/CSS/JS page.
I don't really have any code in regard to this, but below is how I'd like the file directory to be.
index.html
index.css
--- shop
    --- node_modules
    --- public
        shop.html
    --- src
        index.js


One thing I noticed right away is the root file needs to be index.html - this isn't the case. You can mount a React app into any element in any HTML file.

React can be used in many ways - static JS files, with a node server doing SSR; single page, single widget on a page, full SPA. What you want to do is possible. You do not need a sub domain, but the specifics will vary significantly depending on your choices on how to use React. It will deal with web server configuration as well. But the short answer is - yes, you can do this

@BrianThompson thanks for your response. I get an error, Could not find a required file. when there isn't an index.html page. How could I resolve that? I see that I can take any element and inject the react app into it in the shop page, but how could I instantiate the website and react app locally, so that when opening /shop it opens the react app and runs? Would I need to run php -S 127.0.0.1:4300 and npm start simultaneously?

Well it goes back to the "how are you using React" question. Are you using Create React app (CRA)? If so, I believe it runs a development node server for you, but for production it builds static JS files. If you're using something like Next.JS, then the setup becomes very different since you'll need the node server in prod too

I'm using CRA. I already have HTML/CSS/JS files, and I created the react app. How do I put the two together?
